# gridfield manager issue in blackberry please help

Tags: blackberry

I am building an application for BB curve 320*240,where i am adding a backgroundimage of size 240*200.On that background image we are adding gridfield manager with contents.The issue is that the last few contents are getting out of the backgroundimage.How can i fix it to fit within the background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a Manager (VerticalFieldManager, as a simple example), limit its size to 240x200, and set it's background image to your bitmap. Then, add this VerticalFieldManager to your screen, and add all the other controls, like your gridfield manager to the new VerticalFieldManager container.